# Format number as percent in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, percentage

I am trying to simply format a number as a percent with two decimal places. If it is 37 divided by 38 (aka .973684210526315789), I would like it to show 97.36 % in the SQL output. I know it is recommended to do formatting in the Application, however this is for an automated export. This is using SQL Server 2008.

Here is what I have now:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cast(37 as decimal)/cast(38 as decimal)*100)+' %' AS [%]
```

If you could explain what the various parameters are as well in any function that would be helpful.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[M.Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30089557/1501497) could be modified as

```
select Cast(Cast((37.0/38.0)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(5)) + ' %' as Percentage
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it works with any SQL version. Exactly what is needed. Thank you.

Comment: One slight correction to this one. Should be `as varchar(6)` or you won't allow for the edge case of 100.00%

Answer (score 153):

In **SQL Server 2012** and later, there is the [`FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function. You can pass it a `'P'` parameter for percentage. For example:

```
SELECT FORMAT((37.0/38.0),'P') as [Percentage] -- 97.37 %
```

To [support percentage decimal precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#PFormatString), you can use `P0` for no decimals (whole-numbers) or `P3` for 3 decimals (97.368%).

```
SELECT FORMAT((37.0/38.0),'P0') as [WholeNumberPercentage] -- 97 %
SELECT FORMAT((37.0/38.0),'P3') as [ThreeDecimalsPercentage] -- 97.368 %
```

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned I am using SQL Server 2008, so can't use that function.

Comment: Oh, well! In that case, you might find this article helpful, specifically Solution #1: http://raresql.com/2013/08/04/sql-server-how-to-format-values-as-a-percentage/

Comment: what if we only want 97%. Only whole number %

Comment: If you do have SQL Server 2008, the FORMAT function is really handy for this.  Return a whole number by specifying precision like so: SELECT FORMAT(.99, 'P0');

Answer (score 20):

Using FORMAT function in new versions of SQL Server is much simpler and allows much more control:

```
FORMAT(yournumber, '#,##0.0%')
```

Benefit of this is you can control additional things like thousand separators and you don't get that space between the number and '%'.

Comment: Helped me take out hte space. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT cast( cast(round(37.0/38.0,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %'

RESULT:  0.97 %
```

Comment: The required answer is 97.36 % (not 0.97 %)

Answer (score 3):

And for all SQL Server versions

```
SELECT CAST(0.973684210526315789 * 100 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
```

Comment: Would have loved to use FORMAT().  But I am working with SQL 2008.  This worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that might rise is **rounding issue**.

```
.973684210526315789*100   -> 97.37  False
.973684210526315789*100   -> 97.36  True
```

there exist two approaches: `String Functions` and `Numerical Functions`

`String Functions` can avoid *rounding issue*, use functions such as `CAST`( equivalent `CONVERT`) and `LEFT`

```
SELECT LEFT(Cast(.973684210526315789*100 AS VARCHAR(100)), 5) + ' %'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), .973684210526315789*100), 5) + ' %'
```

`Numerical Functions` might bring *rounding issue*, to avoid it use `ROUND` function

```
SELECT LEFT(Round(.973684210526315789*100, 2, 1), 5) + ' %'
```

to avoide using `LEFT` function(String Functions) use `DECIMAL(18,2)` and `NUMERIC(18, 2)` in cast and convert.

```
SELECT Concat(Cast(Round(.973684210526315789 * 100, 2, 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)),' %')

SELECT Concat(CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), Round(.973684210526315789 * 100, 2, 1)),' %')
```

in addition you can use `FORMAT`, `###.##` and `00.00` resemble  *integer part* and *fractional part* and `###.##` should be preferred  to  `00.00`  since it can avoid zero values

```
SELECT FORMAT(Round(.973684210526315789*100, 2, 1), '######.#####')+ ' %' ---> 97.36%

SELECT FORMAT(Round(.973684210526315789*100, 2, 1), '00000.0000')+ ' %' ---> 00097.3600% 

SELECT FORMAT(Round(.973684210526315789*100, 2, 1), '00.00')+ ' %' ---> 97.36%
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=23376ea2e1eed6157cd657731b7046a8)

Answer (score -2):

took the challenge to solve this issue.
comment number 5 (M.Ali) asked for --"The required answer is 97.36 % (not 0.97 %) .."
so for that i'm attaching a photo who compare between post number 3 (sqluser) to my solution. (i'm using the postgre_sql on a mac)

[image]

Comment: Your answer may work for Postgres, but the syntax does not translate to MS Sql Server which is what was requested.

Comment: you right about the to_char line, but if you try only the "Cast" line function it should work for you as you can see in the photo i loaded.