# SQL count with decimal percentage breakdown - how do you limit to 4 decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, altiris

I would like to alter the decimal places to 4 but can't figure it out, help!

--Query

```
select CASE v2.[ie version]
      When '11' Then 'Internet Explorer 11'
      When '9' Then 'Internet Explorer 9'
      When '8' Then 'Internet Explorer 8'
      Else [IE Version] End [IE Version],
COUNT(distinct v1.guid) 'Total Count', COUNT(*) *100.00 / SUM(COUNT(*)) over()'Total Percentage' from vcomputer v1
inner join vIEVersions v2 on v1.guid = v2.guid where v1.ismanaged = '1'
and v2.[IE Version] is not Null and v2.[IE Version] not in ('Unknown', '7', '10')
group by v2.[IE Version] order by 1 desc
```

--Output

```
IE Version               Total Count    Total Percentage
Internet Explorer 9      180            1.7349397590361
Internet Explorer 8      531            5.1180722891566
Internet Explorer 11     9664           93.1469879518072
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number as percent in MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089490/format-number-as-percent-in-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you have to first `CREATE TABLE VIEW` of the decimal percentage breakdown and then call the round function the values of the sum like this example code:

`SELECT ROUND(column_name,decimals) FROM table_name;`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

CAST to decimal should be enough:

```
CAST(COUNT(*) *100.00 / SUM(COUNT(*)) over() as decimal(12,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for example,

> declare @i int=23
>
> select cast(@i*100.00/3 as decimal(10,4))