# I want to calculate ETR_MEET PERCENT ACCORDING TO YES OR NO NAME GROUP BY NAME in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate etr_meet % of name in mysql. How to calculate etr_meet (yes).

```
name          etr_meet 

Anup          yes
Anup          no
Hari          yes
Hari          yes
Shyam         yes
Shyam         yes
Sudip         yes
Sudip         no
Sudip         no
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number as percent in MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089490/format-number-as-percent-in-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query `yes` percent in every `name` group, try this:

```
select
    name,
    concat(count(case when etr_meet = 'yes' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1), '%')
from yourtable
group by name
```